# Db2 IN predicate yields NULL when comparing constant with empty set

Tags: sql, db2, boolean, db2-luw

Consider this query:

```sql
SELECT 
  1 IN (
    SELECT 1 FROM SYSIBM.dual WHERE FALSE  
  ) AS a,
  1 IN (
    SELECT NULL FROM SYSIBM.dual WHERE FALSE
  ) AS b
FROM SYSIBM.dual;
```

Both predicates check if a constant value is in an empty set. The only difference is that one of the empty sets has a `NULL` literal in it, which, in my opinion is irrelevant. Both results should be `FALSE`, because no value is ever in an empty set. However, I'm getting this:

```
A|B|
-|-|
0| |
```

`A` is `FALSE`, as expected, but `B IS NULL`, which makes no sense. Using `CAST(NULL AS INT)` doesn't change anything, in case this could have been because of unknown data types. Is there a logical explanation for this behaviour or is this a bug? Both MySQL and PostgreSQL return `FALSE` for `B`.

```sql
-- PostgreSQL:
SELECT 
  1 IN (
    SELECT 1 WHERE FALSE  
  ) AS a,
  1 IN (
    SELECT CAST(NULL AS INT) WHERE FALSE
  ) AS b

-- MySQL:
SELECT 
  1 IN (
    SELECT 1 WHERE FALSE  
  ) AS a,
  1 IN (
    SELECT NULL WHERE FALSE
  ) AS b
```

A simpler example exposes a similar bug (possibly related to a flawed implementation of Db2's `BOOLEAN` type *in general*):

```sql
SELECT NULL OR FALSE AS a, FALSE OR NULL AS b FROM SYSIBM.dual;
```

Which produces:

```
A|B|
-|-|
0| |
```

Clearly another bug. The order of operands in `OR` shouldn't matter.

I'm using Db2 LUW v11.5.0.0

Comment: That's a bug.  Both A and B should be FALSE.

Comment: No thats a condition check not data selection thats simply wrong syntax in other databases though your db2 supports that syntax for debugging purposes maybe. Try to run same syntax in oracle, or other databases youll get wrong syntax or try `select from.. Where your condition` it will give no records

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja: It's perfectly possible to emulate the syntax in other dialects. But that's not what this question is about.

Comment: Can you raise this with IBM Support?

Comment: @PaulVernon: I don't have a contract (yet). Is there a cheap plan for developers to just dump such issues somewhere? I don't need an SLA...

Comment: Could you test `SELECT 
  1 IN (
    SELECT 1/0 FROM SYSIBM.dual WHERE FALSE  
  ) AS a
FROM SYSIBM.dual;`?  -- PostgreSQL error/MariaDB false and I am really curious about DB2

Comment: @LukaszSzozda: That produces `0` (i.e. `FALSE`) as expected. A shame that PostgreSQL doesn't optimise this. You can try your luck on the mailing list. They should optimise that IMO. This doesn't error on PostgreSQL: `select exists (select 1/0)`

Comment: @LukasEder  I'm not a sales guy, so not sure what the cheapest way to get a support contract is. It might be to take advantage of an offer such as this https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/announcements/free-1000-usd-credit-toward-db2-warehouse-on-ibm-cloud

Comment: @PaulVernon: Sounds like work. Well, I documented this bug here on Stack Overflow...

Comment: Fair enough. I'll take up your observation internally within IBM

Comment: For the record, this has been recognized as a defect and will be fixed in a future Db2 release

Comment: @PaulVernon: Very cool, thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score -1):

IN gives null in comparison with null values due to non availability of `IS NULL` using `IN`

You got the correct output (as these are conditions or like testcases) the results aren't boolean but in form of 0s or data(true) as first query evaluates to false meaning 0 equivalent as IN gives no values will be 0 just like if(check in data).

However, for second it returns null as IN comparison fails in NULL case because of non-availability of `IS NULL` hence true it considers null.
I guess the behaviour is somewhat like ternary conditional operator

```
      Select IN? 0(true) |DATA (includes 
      NULL) (false)
```

Comment: I'm well aware of the fact that `A IN SET` is the same as `A = ANY SET`, which is the same as `A = e1 OR A = e2 ... OR A = en`, and if any `ei IS NULL`, it does not affect the result thanks to 3VL. But that does not explain my observation (which was about *empty sets*) in the least bit.

Comment: The SQL standard says _"If T is empty or if the implied <comparison predicate> is False for every row RT in T, then “R <comp op> <some> T” is False."_, so the result should be `False`.

Comment: Did u really read my answer its condition which is been running not the selection of data db2 supports such debugging syntax. Selecting records using the same condition will give no records